# Using gparted to resize/move a Linux partition

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

I have a USB thumb-drive where I've installed a Live/Bootable linux system.
It works fine!  The partitions are:

- *sdb1* (boot) (unknown) 3gb
- (unallocated 2gb)
- *sdb2* (persistence ext4) 22gb
- (unallocated 4gb)

I boot with a 2nd thumb-drive so that I'm free to edit my 1st one.

I successfully used `gparted` to move/resize *sdb2*.  Why can't I do the same
for *sdb1*?  I've tried clearing/setting its "boot/hidden" flags.  I've tried mounting/unmounting it.  But *sdb1* never seems to unghost its "move/resize" `gparted` menu.

(I'm NOT trying to edit the drive I booted with.)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you mean that you can't make sdb1 grow to 5 GB? Or do you mean that once sdb1 has been extended to 5 GB, you don't see any change when you boot?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the partition _from which_ you have booted?

Comment: The move/resize menu itself is ghosted on sdb1, so I can't even attempt to use it.   (Also, I'm NOT trying to edit the drive I booted with.)  Does my problem have something to do with gparted calling sdb1 "unknown"?  It works fine, but I don't know why it's using some "unknown" filesystem.

Comment: Can you give us (in the question) the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: You might try `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1` to learn the type of file system in the partition.  If it isn't one that GParted knows about (see [GParted Features](http://gparted.org/features.php) then that would explain why the contents of the partition are listed as unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes:

- **Missing resize/move utils**.  `gparted` needs the correct utility installed before it can resize the file system of `/dev/sdb1`.  If the correct utility is not installed, it won't resize.  What the correct utility is depends on the file system.  See the *"View>File System Support"* menu for a table showing what `gparted` has installed.
- **Containing EBR full**. If the partition table on `/dev/sdb` is an `msdos` [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) with an [extended boot record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) (say, `/dev/sdb3`) that contains `/dev/sdb1`, then the contained partition `/dev/sdb1` can be no larger than it's container `/dev/sdb3`.  In which case, enlarging `/dev/sdb1` first requires enlarging `/dev/sdb3`.
- **EBR member mounted**.  If `/dev/sdb1` or any other partition it shares within a containing extended partition is mounted, it can't be resized until it or any other such contained partition is unmounted.
- **Blocked by a bordering EBR**.  If `/dev/sdb1` is not contained in an extended partition, but borders one, (with empty space inside), `/dev/sdb1` cannot cross that border.  To enlarge `/dev/sdb1` would first require shrinking and moving away the bordering extended partition, so that `/dev/sdb1` was left with room to grow into.